# Need Suggestion To become a Java Developer

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Recently i Have Joined a Company which asked me to do work on
Angular(As A Front End) with Spring-Boot(As A back End) in JAVA.
I Have covered A lot of Things in Spring.
But Angular being new to me ,i have no idea how to start. what should i cover html etc to jump in Angular.
It would be helpful if someone can guide me.
Thank You.
:)

Comment: https://angular.io/docs just go through documentation

Comment: Thank You Xesenix..
I will Surely Go Through this.

Comment: You want to become Java or Angular developer?

Comment: Hi Dino..
Actually a Java Developer But Have To Use Angular  as a Front End..
Thats Company Requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of similarity with Angular and Spring boot

Angular uses DI too, but instead of using @Autowired as like SpringBoot you define your dependency in your constructor

Also it has an strong typing usage since it uses typescript, as Java / Kotlin, in Angular you need to define correctly your own interfaces.

Angular also uses Ractive programming, so you will work with rxjs, a library based in observables, where a source emit a value and you subscribe to the source to receive it

The basic Angular unit's are directives, services, components, pipes and modules, in their documentation it is pretty good explained, once you understand this principles you will be good to begin with Angular

https://angular.io/start

https://angular.io/docs

Comment: Thanks A Lot Robert.. :)
But Before Undergoing Angular , Do I need To b Familiar with Html,css,typescript or anything.. ?

Comment: Yh ofc you need basic knowledge of JS and HTML, you will find a lot of similarities with Java and Typescript (mostly Kotlin)

Comment: Thanks A Ton..
I will surely Go Through it..
Have A Nice Day.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have basic knowledge of web development then https://angular.io/docs is the best option. Going through the getting started section will clear your concepts.

Comment: Thank You Brother I will surely Go Through It.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The best option to me when you want to learn `Spring Boot` with `Angular` is to learn **JHipster** https://www.jhipster.tech/.

It's an application generator very powerful but you can use it for lean by exemple.

You could generate a sample and check how they built the Spring Boot app, Angular app and how they communicate (API REST, Security, etc) (ex: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app)

You will also learn a lot of stuff about `JAVA` ecosystem :

1. Maven
2. Docker
3. Liquibase
4. JPA
5. Test
6. and a lot of other things

This is a lot of things to start but very powerful.

Comment: Thanks A ton Brother.. :)